# storing username and password to use in URL

Tags: android, security

I need to extract information from XML. The URL for this xml is comprised of username and password in that URL. 
So basically I can first let the user input his username and password and from that I can generate a URL so I can parse the xml.
My question is, how should I store the username and password first? 
Should I use `SharedPreferences` ? 
or can I just save it to variables in a class?

Comment: If you need the username and password to persist after coming back to the app later then save it to SharedPreferences. If you just need it temporarily save it to variables in a class.

Comment: I don't need the username and password to persist ..